# Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I debugged the code the error that I am getting is after the `obj.close()` statement. I just need the last modified date of the S3 object.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
              .standard()
              .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
              .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
              .build();
    S3Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = s3.getObject("bucketName","abc/1.txt");
    
        obj.getObjectContent();
        Date date = obj.getObjectMetadata().getLastModified();
    
       System.out.println(date);
    }finally {
        if(obj!=null) {
            obj.close();
        }   
    }
```

Error:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 12; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.streamClosed(ResponseEntityProxy.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.close(SdkFilterInputStream.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.close(ProgressInputStream.java:211)
    at com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream.close(S3AbortableInputStream.java:185)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.close(SdkFilterInputStream.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.close(S3ObjectInputStream.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.close(SdkFilterInputStream.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.close(SdkFilterInputStream.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.close(ProgressInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.close(SdkFilterInputStream.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.close(S3ObjectInputStream.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object.close(S3Object.java:225)
```

Comment: Also this is the part of my logs:
[main] WARN com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
21:25:38.161 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Cancelling request execution

Comment: Is that sometime happening or always happens? Did you have network connectivity at that time?

Comment: it always happens, and yes, the network connectivity was there

Comment: How big of the file?

Comment: actually quite small, around 12 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you call `s3.getObject()` but do not read the content that it retrieves. The SDK assumes that if you retrieved the object data you would use it.

If all you care about is the object metadata, you should call `getObjectMetadata()` directly on the `AmazonS3` client object.

Comment: I tried by directly calling getObjectMetadata on AmazonS3 client, but since there is no way to close this object, I think I get the below error log

Comment: ! Causing: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)

Comment: ! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)

Comment: ! at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
! at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
! at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
! at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1338)
! at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1312)
! at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesObjectExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1393)

Comment: The issue has gone now, after restarting the server. Direct call to getObjecMetadata("bucketName, "key") seems to work at least for now